# Google Maps - KML Layer Not Appearing on Map

Tags: node.js, google-maps, express, kml

I'm having an issue where my KML Layer does not appear on an embedded google map on my website.

I made a free website using google sites and uploaded my KML file to it so that I could set the `url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/kmlroute/home/kml'`. The google map itself shows up but the KML layer at that url does not.

My code is below. Does anyone see any syntax errors, logic errors, or anything of the sort that would be stopping my KML Layer from appear on my map???
Any comments, help, and advice is welcome and sincerely appreciated.

```
function initMap(lat, lng) {
  var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};

  // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('bus_1_map'), {
    center: myLatLng,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 12
  });

var route = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/kmlroute/home/kml',
    map: map
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the URL of the XML file itself.
Try this:

```
var route = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'https://sites.google.com/site/kmlroute/home/kml/Bus%2022%20Route.kml.xml?attredirects=0&d=1',
  map: map
});
```

How did I the url?

1. Go to https://sites.google.com/site/kmlroute/home/kml
2. Copy link address of the download arrow.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! This was an issue that was really bugging me... Thank you

Comment: @wf I just accessed my website and now the KML Layer is again not appearing. I haven't changed anything with the code. Is there a chance something one the google site changed/the download link changed (I checked and it was the same as what we had)?